# Erro ao executar o comando ionic cordova run android --device

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova

Quando vou executar o ionic cordova run android --device no meu projeto ele aparece a seguinte mensagem.

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.
```

Meu ionic.info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI         : 5.0.1 (C:\Users\DEV02\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.1.0
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.14

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.4

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Execute o comando com "--no-native-run" no final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete toda a pasta `node_modules` dentro do seu projeto e depois rode o seguinte comando:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Vai voltar a funcionar.

Comment: Deletei a pasta node_modules, e removi e adicionei plataforma,mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Você deu stop no serviço antes do procedimento?

Comment: Sim,eu parei tudo, e dei o comando, teria que fazer algo a mais ?

Comment: Para tudo, exclui a pasta, reinicia a máquina e rode o comando, Este comando tem que resolver o problema.

Comment: Fiz todo o procedimento,mas ele ainda continua exibindo uma mensagem de error:

Comment: Error: Command failed: C:\Users\DEV02\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/adb -s 0054735553 shell getprop

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.